# Rails 4 InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: jquery, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep running into `InvalidAuthenticityToken` errors with an app I'm working on at the moment. I use rollbar to track all the errors and in each case the user sends an HTTP X-Csrf-Token Header. The requests are all AJAX requests sent using vanilla jQuery (with jquery_ujs). Users frequently have multiple tabs open at once - not sure if this could have anything to do with it.

I've looked at the source code in rails that validates the authenticity tokens and I can't see any reason they would become invalid unless the session somehow expired.

Any ideas as to why I keep running into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say this is likely due to the session expiring before the user triggers an AJAX request on tab open long ago.

In Rails 4 the default strategy to handle unverified requests is to raise an InvalidAuthenticityToken error:

From /app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

From actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:

```
class Exception
  def initialize(controller)
    @controller = controller
  end

  def handle_unverified_request
    raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
  end
end
```

You can use :null_session as the unverified request handling strategy, if you want to prevent the error being raised.

You can also try increasing the session timeout to see if the problem goes away or becomes less frequent.

For a more in-depth explanation of Rails 4 new CSRF protection defaults you can read:

[Forgery Protection Strategy](http://alexcoco.com/forgery-protection-strategy/)

Comment: diegog is probably correct. Assuming that you're able to confirm that this is the problem, you might be able to set up a JavaScript timer to automatically refresh the page when the session has expired. Increasing the session timeout, as diegog suggests, might not work if a user closes her laptop in the evening and then interacts with an AJAX link on the page several hours or days later.